# C++ - cast int to bytes and write corresponding test method

Tags: c++

I wrote a method intToBytes() and an corresponding method to test this function. In VisualStudio-Debugger I can see that the value '2C' is the last entry of the vector. Moreover it seems that I have some problems finding the right option to compare the two arrays in my test method. Thanks for your help.

```
vector<unsigned char> intToBytes(int paramInt){
    vector<unsigned char> arrayOfByte(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        arrayOfByte[3 - i] = (paramInt >> (i * 8));
    }
    return arrayOfByte;
}

int intToBytesTest(){
    int test1 = 44;
    vector<unsigned char> test1Vector = intToBytes(test1);
    BYTE exp1[] = {0x2C , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 };
    BYTE act1[] = {test1Vector.at(0), test1Vector.at(1), test1Vector.at(2), test1Vector.at(3)};
    if (exp1 != act1){ 
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check what endian-ness your chip supports: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @DonWakefield: All platforms targeted by Visual Studio (mentioned in the question) are little endian.

Comment: Yeah. He mentioned that '2C' was "the last entry", and he does reversal of the bytes in his code, so I was pointing out that this was expected (whereas his BYTE test vector puts it first). Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: And your question is what? You don't say what does not compile, what does not do what you expected, what you expected if not what it does? We are not seers. You have to tell us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare two raw `BYTE` arrays using `==`. You're actually comparing to see if they're the same array, not if the arrays are identical.

Instead you can use `std::vector` as it has an overload for `==` that compares two instances to see if they're identical.